# How to insert pawns on the board?

Tags: python

I created board, but I've confused with pawns.

```
board = [[(x,y) for x in range(1,9)] for y in range(1,9)]
for k in range(len(board)):
    print('| |' * len(board))
```

I want to see something like that:

```
| || || || || || || || |
|P||P||P||P||P||P||P||P|
| || || || || || || || |
| || || || || || || || |
| || || || || || || || |
| || || || || || || || |
|P||P||P||P||P||P||P||P|
| || || || || || || || |
```

But which way can I choose to put pawns on the boards?
Should I use double for loops to check if coordinates equal or exist alternative way to?

```
def pawn():
    coordinates = board[1][1]
    return coordinates

for i in range(len(board)):
    for j in range(8):
        if board[i][j] == pawn():
           print('|P|' * len(board))
        else:
           print('| |')
```

Comment: As a side note, I think your board would be easier to look at if you used a space instead of an 'X' for the empty squares on the board.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that could work:

```
import numpy as np
board = np.empty((8,8)).tolist()
for k in range(len(board)):
    if k == 1 or k ==6:
        board[k]= ['|p|','|p|','|p|','|p|','|p|','|p|','|p|','|p|']
    else:
        board[k]= ['|x|','|x|','|x|','|x|','|x|','|x|','|x|','|x|']
[print(''.join(b)) for b in board ]
```

but I'm not sure if it is what you wanted. In that case board is a 2D matrix which is shape like the board.
if it is for chess, you need a 'P' for white and a 'p' for black.

Comment: What is the purpose of pulling in `numpy` for this? Is it that difficult to create a list of lists?

Comment: I don't think making a list of lists is the aim of the question here. It is just I use a lot this module in my scripts.

Comment: I get that you find `numpy` to be convenient and handy since you use it all the time. The problem is that a new person might think from looking at your answer that `numpy` is a requirement to solve their problem. For that matter, the OP already includes the code to create the list of lists, you could just drop the first two lines from your answer, and you would still be addressing the main aim of the question (referencing `board` as the variable as defined in the OP's question).

Comment: Yes I understand that. I wasn't thinking that it could be disturbing in that way.

Answer (score 0):

The initial position of pawns is row 2 and 7. You can check the `for` loop index and set their positions. Something like:

```
board = [[(x,y) for x in range(1,9)] for y in range(1,9)]
pawnRows = [1, 6]  # 0 based index

for k in range(len(board)):
    if k in pawnRows:
        print('|P|' * len(board))
    else:
        print('|X|' * len(board))
```

Answer (score 0):

Making it more general, you can use an `array` or `pandas.DataFrame` to remember the state of the board

## Data definition

Setting up the pieces

```
piece = collections.namedtuple('piece', ('value', 'mark'))
EMPTY = piece(0, '|X|')
PAWN = piece(1, '|P|')
pieces = {p.value: p for p in (EMPTY, PAWN)}
```

You can define as much pieces as you want, and even give the separate colours

## Defining the board

```
boardsize = (8,8)
board = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1] * boardsize[0]] * boardsize[1]) * EMPTY.value
```

## Setting up the pieces

```
pawn_positions = [(1, 1), (3, 4), (7, 6)]

for pawn in pawn_positions:
    board.loc[pawn] = PAWN.value
```

Results in something like this

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

## Printing the board with marks

```
for row_nr, row in board.applymap(lambda x: pieces[x].mark).iterrows():
    print(''.join(row) + '\n')
```

gives

```
|X||X||X||X||X||X||X||X|
|X||P||X||X||X||X||X||X|
|X||X||X||X||X||X||X||X|
|X||X||X||X||P||X||X||X|
|X||X||X||X||X||X||X||X|
|X||X||X||X||X||X||X||X|
|X||X||X||X||X||X||X||X|
|X||X||X||X||X||X||P||X|
```